# Prove this general inequality

Tags: inequalities

Let $a_{k},b_{k}>0$,show that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{b_{k}(b_{1}+b_{2}+\cdots+b_{k})}{a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{k}}<2\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{b^2_{i}}{a_{i}}\tag{1}$$

I  known  prove $b_{k}=1$,because  it become
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{k}{a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{k}}<2\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{a_{i}}$$ see [mathstack](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98483/a-version-of-hardys-inequality-involving-reciprocals/108598#108598)

But How prove $(1)$?

Comment: What makes you think the inequality holds?

Comment: It is said from http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1289401_inequality

Comment: I find the question very nice, but typically such questions seem to be better suited for math.SE -- hence I voted to put it on hold.